# Other way in sending key via javascript in a dropdown textbox because it does not work sometimes

Tags: java, selenium

The reason for sending keys via js is sending it slower on a textbox dropdown , when you type fast it does not type it fully because I think it checks for data in the textbox ( sample is sendkeys=product it types like prdct ) every type of letter shows the suggestion below.
The problem also is sometimes it does not select the right product.

tried implicit/explicit wait , tried sending keys then selecting , tried sending keys and pressing enter

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;


    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='tablerow tdupdate']//img")).click();
    System.out.println("Successful in clicking finalize button");

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    WebElement inputproduct = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='txtdepartment txtenter_event']"));
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'sample department');", inputproduct);
```

What I want is to select the right product always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to try sending every character on input and then add static wait for some fraction of milliseconds since input webelemet is checking for data everytime

```
    inputproduct.sendKeys("s");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    inputproduct.sendKeys("a");
    Thread.sleep(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `Actions`, like this:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@class='txtdepartment txtenter_event']")));
WebElement inputproduct = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='txtdepartment txtenter_event']"));

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(inputproduct).click().build().perform();
act.moveToElement(inputproduct).sendKeys("value").build().perform();
```

Please add `WebDriverWait`, following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code snippet instead of javascript executor.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 
10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
(By.xpath("//input[@class='txtdepartment txtenter_event']")));


WebElement inputproduct = driver.findElement
(By.xpath("//input[@class='txtdepartment txtenter_event']"));

inputproduct.sendkeys("test");
```